# Finding an analytic function such that real part is the given function.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I am reading the book Complex Analysis by Lars V Ahlfors. In the book he uses a nice method without involving integration to evaluate $f$ given that the real part of the function is $U$.

The method is as follows:

The conjugate function $\overline {f(z)}$ has the derivative zero with respect to $z$ and we may therefore consider it as a function of $\overline z$. Call this function $g(\overline z)$.$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x+iy)+g(x-iy)]$$
If we substitute $x=z/2,y=z/2i$, we obtain$$u(z/2,z/2i)=\frac{1}{2}[f(z)+g(0)]$$

Here in this he assumes he can substitute complex values for $x$ and $y$. So I want to prove that the function $f$ obtained as above is analytic and has the real part as $u(x,y)$. I concluded that since the function $f=2u(z/2,z/2i)+c$ is not a function of $\overline z$, if $u(x,y)$ is rational function then $f $ so derived will be analytic except at poles.  But now I am unable to show that $u(x,y)$ is the real part of the function $f$. If anyone can help in solving this it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above method actually fails in  the case of functions like $\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ . Here when we substitute the denominator of the function becomes zero.